# (ADD_TO_STORY) facebook unable to access my file

Tags: java, android, xml, flutter, dart

I'm currently trying to share content from my app to social media (like facebook, instagram...) and i'm having a problem of authorisation from facebook to access my image, when i test it i get this message:

`Facebook cannot access this media right now, please try sharing again`

i guess i setup my manifest.xml / fileprovider.xml file the wrong way. But can't find a solution.

here's my share button (`/lib/`):

```
new IconButton(
   icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.facebook),
   onPressed: () async {
      final imageFile = await widget.handleScreen.capture();
      Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      String tempPath = tempDir.path;
      File file = File(tempDir.path + '/img.jpeg');
      await file.writeAsBytes(imageFile);
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
         AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
            action: 'com.facebook.stories.ADD_TO_STORY',
            data: file.path,
            type: 'image/jpeg',
            arguments: {'com.facebook.platform.extra.APPLICATION_ID': 'myappid'},
         );
         await intent.launch();
      }
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
   },
),
```

Here's my mannifest.xml (`/android/app/src/main/`):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   package="com.example.app">

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

   <application
      android:label="app"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

      <provider
         android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
         android:authorities="com.example.app.fileprovider"
         android:exported="false"
         android:grantUriPermissions="true"
         tools:replace="android:authorities">
         <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
      </provider>

      <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderMY_FB_APPID"
         android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
         android:exported="true" />

      <activity
         android:name=".MainActivity"
         android:launchMode="singleTop"
         android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
         
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
         android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
         android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
               android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
               android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"/>

            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
               android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
               android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"/>

            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
           android:name="flutterEmbedding"
           android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And here's my filepaths.xml (`/android/app/src/main/res/xml/`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <cache-path name="image" path="/"/>
</paths>
```

i know there's is package for social sharing on flutter (social_share and social_share_plugin) but they doesn't allow user to send background image and stickers.

Thanks for your help and your time